# Is there a login for humans available?

Tags: discussion, login

I have not been visiting askubuntu for a while and was now confronted with OpenID.
I will never be able to remember a password from 8 unique digits with upper and lower characters and special characters! I am sure I will ask them to reset my password every time I want to login... 
Is it possible to use a more traditional login with passwords that a human being can remember?
(I do not want to use any of the social media logins for privacy reasons)

Answer (score 5):

There are several other ways to log into your account *without* using the SE OpenID service. We support Google (including Google's two-factor authentication), Facebook, Yahoo, and any other site that acts as an OpenID provider. You can use any combination of these credentials without any loss in functionality.

The reason for the password requirements was discussed by one of our developers here — [Can Stack Exchange change the password criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126088/98786) Being an open OpenID provider, your login credentials are available for use with any service that supports OpenID. Granted, most people probably don't use their Stack Exchange accounts elsewhere, but the developers have been steadfast in their belief that they err on the side of stricter security practices.

I understand your criticism of the password requirements, but I hope you find the requirements behind any one of these alternatives acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a password manager like Lastpass[addon to Firefox/chrome] to managed all your passwords.  Just have to remember one password.

Comment: I hesitate using these but there might be no way around in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular reason to use the Stack Exchange OpenID service. You could sign up for an account with a less restrictive OpenID provider instead (e.g. MyOpenID, which has no password restrictions at all), and sign in with that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I wonder why they make things so complicated.
To me using such services is the kind of improvement that we have seen with Ebay when they removed wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Write your password down on paper! you can't hack that!

Comment: haven't thought of this trick... But common, am I the only one that dislikes having my activities tracked?